# Kindly Assist With Vb.net Error

Tags: vb.net

The first search I perform is always successful but trying to search again after that I get the following error. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Vb.net Error]

Comment: The error itself is already telling you what the issue is. From the code in that image, your dataset doesn't have any table if the eval is true

Comment: Nick, welcome to SO. Kindly take the [tour] to gain an understanding of how things work round here. Your question has been answered. You should consider marking it as accepted. I'd also strongly advise looking over the duplicate link as it will help you gain a better understanding of your error.

Comment: Kindly read [ask] and take the [tour].  Questions need the related code in the question as text, not links and not pictures.  The same for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

As [EdSF points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385692/kindly-assist-with-vb-net-error#comment71919821_42385692) you have no tables after the first search. This is because you set `IsFind` to ensure you've already searched, but you create a new dataset anyway `datast = New DataSet` which will have no tables.

If this was unintended, then you can do:

`If datast IsNot Nothing AndAlso datast.Tables IsNot Nothing AndAlso datast.Tables("tblproduct") IsNot Nothing Then`

Or the short way (VS2015+) using null propagation.

`datast?.Tables?("tblproduct")?.Clear()`

If this is intended, and you want a new `DataSet` every time, then just remove that `If` block, it does nothing.

Comment: Seems like using null propagation `?.` in this kind of situation makes code to be less understandable for others.

Comment: It does, but the option is there if they so choose